# Htaccess - Redirect if URL does not contain at least three numbers

Tags: .htaccess

I'm struggling to get this htaccess redirect to work.  I want to redirect any URL that does not contain at least three numbers in a row.  I started with the following and it worked perfectly for redirecting any URL that DID have three numbers in a row:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [0-9]{3,20} [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) "https\:\/\/info\.mywebsite\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

However, I tried to modify that with the exclamation mark to make the condition NOT match three numbers in a row:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !([0-9]{3,20}) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) "https\:\/\/info\.mywebsite\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

But that doesn't seem to work as expected.  Am I missing something with turning this expression into a not match?

Comment: Example URL? And btw., the substitution part of the RewriteRule is not a regular expression, so there’s no need to escape any characters in there like you’re currently doing.

Comment: That should work. Could it be that you are simply looking at cached results in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

Having previously experimented with the opposite 301 (**permanent**) redirect then the results are most probably cached (by the browser) from the earlier redirect. It is a good idea to test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching issues.

Note also that the `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the URL-path only, so if the *digits* are contained in the query string part of the URL-path then your condition will fail.

The *quantifier* `{3,20}` matches from 3 to 20 characters, if you want "at least three" then use the quantifier `{3,}` (no upper bound).

You don't need the capturing subpatterns, ie. surrounding parentheses `(...)` on the regex since you are not using backreferences anywhere. Incidentally, you can't capture subpattern on a negated regex.

You don't need the additional condition (`RewriteCond` directive) - this can all be done with the `RewriteRule` directive only.

The `NC` flag is not required here - you are checking digits only.

For example:

```
RewriteRule !\d{3,} https://info.mywebsite.com/" [R=302,L]
```

As noted in comments, the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string is a regular string, not a regex, so does not require any special backslash escaping (although colons and slashes don't need escaping anyway in Apache regex).